# KineticJS Sprite not working correctly on iPad

Tags: ipad, sprite, kineticjs

I'm doing a little game, using KineticJS. For the animation of the character movement, i'm using a spritesheet.

In desktop (with different browsers), the character animation is doing great, as in Android too. But, on iPad, it gets wrong. I'm pretty sure it's because the iOS platform, because neither Safari, Chrome or UIWebView displays the correct behaviour of the Spritesheet.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code for us to see?

Comment: Bodman, sorry for the late response. In fact, I already know what's happening. It has something to do with the resolution of png images on iOS, that cannot be superior to a certain dimension (1024x1024, I guess). 

Again, sorry for the long waiting, and thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done. The bug was related to the maximum resolution iOS devices supports.

Comment: Could you give us some code that fixed this issue? I'm trying to resolve this now and I'm using version 5.0.2. Many thanks

Comment: Hi @AndrewJuniorHoward. It's a limitation of the iOS environment. Your image can't exceed a certain size. I was using a sprite in my project, and I had to reduce the size of it. Hope it helps. Cheers!